# Securing static resources in a Spring Boot App

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I want to secure all content in the 'static' folder of a Spring Boot app.

I have tried all sorts of combinations in my security config including:

```
.antMatchers("/resources/**").authenticated()
.antMatchers("/resources/static/**").authenticated()
.antMatchers("/static/**").authenticated()
```

None of these work. What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Those folders are served, but they're not actually within the path of any web request, so they don't match to anything. A proper solution would be to put your static resources within folders, eg. `src/main/resources/static/css/mystyle.css` and to add matchers to those, eg. `.antMatchers("/css/**").authenticated()`.

Comment: Thanks but, I have tried that and it doesn't work.

Comment: I'm using Spring Boot 1.5.1.RELEASE and my static resources are in src/main/resources/static. I want to prevent unauthorized users downloading certain javascript files.

Comment: Show your complete configuration class with all anotations.

Comment: It's ok. I have a work around. I created a folder call app-js and moved all the JavaScript I wanted to secure into this folder and that works.

Answer (score 0):

Disable the default spring-boot resource mappings with

```
spring.resources.add-mappings=false
```

to

```
application.properties
```